# Read and write array from txt in Verilog

Tags: file, save, load, verilog

First of all I want to say that I'm running the simulation in ADS (Advanced Design System 2017) through a Verilog model compiled in ModelSim.

My objective is loading data from a .txt file into the testbench as input in order to run the simulation, and afterwards save the results of this simulation in another .txt file.

Here is the content for the input test .txt file called "param.txt":

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

And here is my Verilog testbench code:

```
`include "disciplines.vams"


module resistor(p,n);
electrical p,n;
parameter real R=50.0;
integer file;
integer out;
real pwm_A[0:50];
integer i;
integer j=1;


analog begin

    @(initial_step) // Initial Conditions
    begin


////////////// Read

file=$fopen("param.txt","r");

    if (file)  $display("File was opened successfully : %0d", file);
    else       $display("File was NOT opened successfully : %0d", file);

    for (i=1; i<50; i=i+1) begin  
        pwm_A[i]=$fscanf(file,"%d",j);
        j = j+1;
    end



////////////// Write


out=$fopen("out.txt","w");

    for (i=1; i<=15; i=i+1) begin  

        $fwrite(out,"%d\n",pwm_A[i]);

    end

// Trying to manually display data
$fdisplay(out,123);


$fclose(file);
$fclose(out);


end

// Simulation (doesnt matter)
V(p,n) <+ R * I(p,n);


end
endmodule
```

The simulation log has no errors or warnings:

```
File was opened successfully : -32
```

But the output .txt file called "out.txt" generates this:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
0
0
0
0
0
123
```

Instead of the original data.

It's noticeable that the '123' manually introduced value has no problems to be written, but the rest of the data are '0' or '1'.

May anyone spot the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line here

```
pwm_A[i]=$fscanf(file,"%d",j);
```

should read

```
$fscanf(file,"%d",pwm_A[i]);
```

The `$fscanf` *system function* is the opposisite of `$fdisplay` - the function outputs into variables in its argument list. It *returns* the number of items successfully read from the line. This will (hopefully) be 1 for the first ten lines and will be 0 for the next lines. So, you should really check that number and do something if it's not what you expect, eg:

```
count = $fscanf(file,"%d",pwm_A[i]);
if (count != 1) 
  // whatever
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. In order to test this code I established 15 values for seeing that the first 10 were 1 and the rest were 0, so I could see anything was going wrong. 

In my real design I do know how many values the .txt has, so this is not a problem.

Let's suppose the initial .txt has 10 values (1-10). Using your corrected line:

for (i=1; i<10; i=i+1) begin  
  
 count = $fscanf(file,"%d",pwm_A[i]);
 
end

I get this error: 

Error: Incorrect target supplied to integer-valued $fscanf field.

Any suggestions? count is defined as integer at the beginning

Comment: Yes, but this is a different question. Please ask a new question instead. The idea of Stack Overflow is not only to help the original asker of the question, but also to provide a useful resource for future Googlers.

Comment: Of course, here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55042142/read-and-write-from-txt-in-verilog