# Read and write from txt in Verilog

Tags: file, save, verilog

First of all I want to say that I'm running the simulation in ADS (Advanced Design System 2017) through a Verilog model compiled in ModelSim.

My objective is loading data from a .txt file into the testbench as input in order to run the simulation, and afterwards save the results of this simulation in another .txt file.

Here is the content for the input test .txt file called "param.txt":

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

And here is my Verilog testbench code:

```
`include "disciplines.vams"


module resistor(p,n);
electrical p,n;
parameter real R=50.0;
integer file;
integer out;
real pwm_A[0:10];
integer i;
integer count;


analog begin

    @(initial_step) // Initial Conditions
    begin


////////////// Read

file=$fopen("param.txt","r");

    if (file)  $display("File was opened successfully : %0d", file);
    else       $display("File was NOT opened successfully : %0d", file);

    for (i=1; i<=5; i=i+1) begin  
         count = $fscanf(file,"%d",pwm_A[i]);
    end



////////////// Write


out=$fopen("out.txt","w");

    for (i=1; i<=5; i=i+1) begin  
        $fwrite(out,"%d\n",pwm_A[i]);
    end


$fclose(file);
$fclose(out);


end

// Simulation (doesnt matter)
V(p,n) <+ R * I(p,n);


end
endmodule
```

The simulation throws this error:

```
Error: Incorrect target supplied to integer-valued $fscanf field.
```

May anyone spot the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read and write array from txt in Verilog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55039421/read-and-write-array-from-txt-in-verilog)

Comment: It's not duplicated, i'ts just another issue!

Comment: Hi davmc! Yes, but your source code still contains the same issue as the previous question, where Matthew suggested to change `pwm_A[i]=$fscanf(file,"%d",j);` to `count = $fscanf(file,"%d",pwm_A[i]);`.

Comment: This does seem to be the same question again. In the comment below the other question, you were asking about an error message: "Error: Incorrect target supplied to integer-valued $fscanf field. Any suggestions?" The code in this question hasn't got the fix from my answer in the other question.

Comment: You both are right, sorry, fixed now

Comment: You declared `pwm_A` as a `real`. Did you try to declare it as an `integer`? Based on the error message you provided, this could be the problem. If you actually need to load real numbers instead of integers, you might want to change the `%d` specifier. See [this reference](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) on the several C specifiers.

Comment: There are differences between C and Verilog-AMS formatted input and output. Go for the Verilog-AMS standard https://accellera.org/images/downloads/standards/v-ams/VAMS-LRM-2-4.pdf.

Comment: Thank you guys, problem solved changing `pwm_A`as a `integer`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have declared `pwm` as an array of reals whilst using the `%d` *format specifier* to both read and write the file. You need to either

i) change `pwm` to be an array of integers or

ii) change the `%d` format specifier to `%f` in the `$fscanf` and `$fwrite` system function calls.

The `%d` format specifier is expecting to read and will write a decimal integer.